Understand data difference from devices installed in Play Console
When we open the Play Console, we come across the list of apps and we can pin them.
On this screen we have previews of the number of active users and installations.
By clicking on the app, we have the dashboard with more complete data and graphs.
However, the information differs from the app listing.
After all, who is more up-to-date?
Installed Base and Acquired Users:

Total installed base:

Acquired users:

It's the same information, but it's never the same.
I just wanted to understand what data is most current.
